# Unable to build mule 3.5.0 source code

Tags: mule

I am attempting to build the Mule ESB 3.5.0 Community Runtime found at https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/releases/tag/mule-3.5.0

If I build using maven and skip the tests everything is fine.

However if I leave the tests enabled a few fail and the rest are skipped.

I have tried building each maven module individually in the order they are listed in the parent POM using the setups listed below:

Please could someone advise to any additional steps or environment setup required in order to successfully build the source?

---

### Setup #1

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop (64bit)
java-7-oracle JDK (64bit)
Maven 3.0.5

The results are as follows:

     buildtools      - ALL TESTS PASS
     core            - ALL TESTS PASS
     distributions   - ALL TESTS PASS
     examples        - ALL TESTS PASS
     modules         - failed on Management Extensions:
                                 testDefaultJmxAgent(org.mule.management.JmxAgentEmptyConfigurationTestCase)
                                 testDefaultJmxAgent(org.mule.management.JmxAgentDefaultConfigurationWithRMITestCase)
     patterns        - ALL TESTS PASS
     tools                - ALL TESTS PASS
     transports      - failed on HTTP Transport:
                                 createHttpServerConnectionWithHttpConnectorProperties(org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnectionTestCase)
     tests           -failed on Integration Tests:
                                   testOutboundInMiddleOfFlow(org.mule.test.construct.FlowOutboundInMiddleOfFlowTestCase)
                                   validatesDbConnectorGenericMySqlOverriddenTemplateResolution(org.mule.spring.config.NewDatabaseMuleArtifactTestCase)
                                   verifiesDerby(org.mule.spring.config.DatabaseMuleArtifactTestCase)
```

---

### Setup #2

```
Windows 7 Pro (64bit)
Oracle Jave JDK 1.6.0_31 (64bit)
Maven 3.2.1 

The results are as follows:

     buildtools      - ALL TESTS PASS
     core            - Failed
                          testFullStackTraceWithoutMessage(org.mule.util.ExceptionUtilsTestCase)
                          dateTimeIsAfter[0](org.mule.el.context.ServerContextTestCase)
                          testIsSupportedJdkVersion(org.mule.util.JdkVersionUtilsTestCase)
                          testRecommendedJdkVersion(org.mule.util.JdkVersionUtilsTestCase)
                          testValidateJdk5(org.mule.util.JdkVersionUtilsTestCase)
```

---

### Setup #3

```
Windows 7 Pro (64bit)
Oracle Jave JDK 1.7.0_51 (64bit)
Maven 3.2.1 

The results are as follows:

     buildtools      - ALL TESTS PASS
     core            - Failed
                          testFullStackTraceWithoutMessage(org.mule.util.ExceptionUtilsTestCase)
                          dateTimeIsAfter[0](org.mule.el.context.ServerContextTestCase)
                          testIsSupportedJdkVersion(org.mule.util.JdkVersionUtilsTestCase)
                          testRecommendedJdkVersion(org.mule.util.JdkVersionUtilsTestCase)
                          testValidateJdk5(org.mule.util.JdkVersionUtilsTestCase)
```

Regards
Kumaran

Answer (score 0):

- Mule 3.5 has to be compiled against Java6.
- Theoretically it can be compiled on windows but I would rather try with Linux/Mac.
- Make sure you allocate enough ram `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx4000m"`
- Read carefully the [BUILD](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/BUILD.md) instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Victor.

I followed your instructions. But still I get the same test failures.

Comment: Please provide the report log of each of the failing tests.

Comment: Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.218 sec <<< FAILURE!
testDefaultJmxAgent(org.mule.management.JmxAgentDefaultConfigurationWithRMITestCase)  Time elapsed: 0.209 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Should not connect
 at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
 at org.mule.management.JmxAgentDefaultConfigurationWithRMITestCase.testDefaultJmxAgent(JmxAgentDefaultConfigurationWithRMITestCase.java:35)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

Comment: Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.414 sec <<< FAILURE!
testDefaultJmxAgent(org.mule.management.JmxAgentEmptyConfigurationTestCase)  Time elapsed: 0.407 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.net.ConnectException
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:35)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
 at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:46)

Comment: Tests run: 17, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.968 sec <<< FAILURE!
createHttpServerConnectionWithHttpConnectorProperties(org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnectionTestCase)  Time elapsed: 0.215 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1024> but was:<1152>
 at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
 at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:647)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:128)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:472)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:456)
 at